# Trouble Solving Complex Num Equation with Conjugate and Powers

Tags: linear-algebra

The equation is as follows: $z^4 - 16\bar{z}^2 = 0$

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nli1j.png

Trying to solve this with cartesian coordinates clearly isn't working, but even with polar coordinates I don't really know how to go about solving this...

what I know is that:

$|z| = |z^*| = r$ and $z = r(\cosθ + \sinθ) $

=> meaning $z^4 = r^4(\cos4θ + \sin4θ)$, $(z^*)^2 = r^2(\cos2θ - \sin2θ)$

so overall we have $r^4(\cos4θ + \sin4θ) = 16r^2(\cos2θ - \sin2θ)$.

I really don't know which direction to go here...
I have the solution to the question but I want to understand the steps you use to solve this because I'm finding myself stuck here

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution:
\begin{align}
z^4-16(z^*)^2 &= 0\\
z^4 &= 16(z^*)^2\\
&\text{let } z = r\exp(i\theta)\\
r^4\exp(4i\theta)&=16r^2\exp(-2i\theta)\\
&\to r^4 = 16r^2\to r=0\text{ or }r=4\\
&\to \text{for }r=0, z=0\\
&\to \text{for }r=4, z=4\exp(i\theta)\text{ and}\\
\exp(4i\theta)&= \exp(-2i\theta)\\
4\theta &=-2\theta + 2\pi k, k\in\Bbb{Z}\\
6\theta &= 2\pi k, k\in\Bbb{Z}\\
\theta &=\frac{\pi}{3},k\in\Bbb{Z}
\end{align}
You get 6 angles giving distinct solutions:
\begin{equation}
\theta =\frac{\pi}{3},k = 0,1,2,3,4,5\;.
\end{equation}

Answer (score 0):

You should have $i$'s in all of your expressions involving $\sin$. This gives you
$$r^4(\cos(4\theta)+i\sin(4\theta))=16r^2(\cos(2\theta)-i\sin(2\theta)).$$ 
Taking the norm of both sides gives you $r^4=16r^2$, so either $r=0$ or $r^2=16$ and $r=4$. Equating real and imaginary parts tells you $\cos(4\theta)=\cos(2\theta)$, and $\sin(4\theta)=-\sin(2\theta)$. A little bit of thought tells you that $\theta=0,\theta=\pi/3, 2\pi/3, \pi, 4\pi/3, 5\pi/3$ are the only solutions.

Comment: oh, the part I failed to realize here was that I can address the norm and polar parts separately. this looks so simple now. thanks a lot. how to mark this as solved?

Comment: $z=0$ is also a solution.

Comment: and $z=4\exp(i2\pi/3)$ is also a solution.

Comment: Thank you, I will edit to include those solutions I missed!

Comment: there should be a total of 7 solutions, which are z = -4, 0, 4, (+/-)2 (+/-)2iroot(3). I forgot to mention that the question wanted the solutions in cartesian form and not polar.

Comment: Ah yes I was listing solutions for $\theta<\pi$, but $\pi$, $4\pi/3$, and $5\pi/3$ are also solutions.